# Alter day or month of datetime.date without subclass or helper functions that use the constructor

Tags: python, date, datetime, calendar

I receive variously formatted dates or parts of dates and after getting them into `datetime.date` format, I would like to adjust the month field or the day field without calling the constructor for a whole new `datetime.date` object.

The data can be any of the following kinds of things:

```
'2012.01.01'
'194311'
'1865/08/30'
'1701'
 ... etc
```

For underspecified dates, I will want to push them either to January 1, to the first of the provided month, to the end of the provided month, or to December 31. A year must be provided and won't be changed.

`dateutil.parser.parse` handles all of these nicely, except for the convention that it fills in missing months and/or days with the current month and/or day:

```
In [11]: dateutil.parser.parse('2012/04')
Out[11]: datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 10, 0, 0)

In [12]: dateutil.parser.parse('1865')
Out[12]: datetime.datetime(1865, 2, 10, 0, 0)

In [13]: dateutil.parser.parse('1920.03.27')
Out[13]: datetime.datetime(1920, 3, 27, 0, 0)
```

After getting into `datetime.datetime` format, I can call the `datetime` function `date` to effectively cast as a `datetime.date`, so that part is trivial.

What I would like to avoid is writing a helper function that must go through the pains of calling a constructor, like so:

```
def adjust_to_jan1(date_str):
    temp = dateutil.parser.parse(date_str).date()
    return datetime.date(temp.year, 1, 1)
```

or

```
def adjust_to_month_end(date_str):
    import calendar
    temp = dateutil.parser.parse(date_str).date()
    last_day = calendar.monthrange(temp.year, temp.month)
    return datetime.date(temp.year, temp.month, last_day)
```

or

```
def adjust_to_last_weekdat(date_str):
    import calendar
    temp = dateutil.parser.parse(date_str).date()
    last_weekday = max([elem for x in calendar.monthcalendar(temp.year, 
                                                             temp.month) 
                        for elem in x[0:5]])
    return datetime.date(temp.year, temp.month, last_weekday)
```

Since I work with this data interactively very often, it gets to be a pain to define these kinds of functions all the time. It gets more complicated: last week day that's not a holiday in some arbitrary group of countries... last weekday except it can be last Saturday if the year is before a certain year...

What I'd like to do is just *declare* the change that I want, such as:

```
some_date = datetime.date(2012, 1, 20)
some_date.day = 1
```

But this is not allowed.

I could subclass `datetime` but then I have to worry about my subclass not doing any damage and whether it's portable for other folks using some of the scripts that come from the interactive work.

Any other solutions would be appreciated.

If you don't think there is a better approach than either subclassing or writing lots of these helper functions, that's fine, but I'd prefer to leave comments and answers *only* for any proposals that are different from that -- rather than getting lots of responses that say "This looks fine as it is" or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`datetime.date` objects are immutable, but they do have a [`.replace()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace) to do what you want:

```
somedate = somedate.replace(day=1)
```

The method returns a *new* object with the desired values swapped out.

For completeness sake, there are also [`datetime.datetime.replace()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) and  [`datetime.time.replace()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.replace) methods.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for.